# RewriteRule pointing domain resolved as 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I'm trying to setup proxy in apache like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.public.domain
...
    RewriteRule "^/dir/(.*)" "http://x-service.local/$1" [P,L]
...
```

there is also another vhost conf on the same server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName x-service.local
...
```

in `/etc/hosts` on apache server I have following entry:

```
x-service.local 127.0.0.1
```

When I do `curl test.public.domain/dir/xxx` from my workstation I got 5xx code.

When I do `curl x-service.local/xxx` from server itself I got 200 code.

When I change

```
x-service.local 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
x-service.local 192.168.1.1
```

`curl test.public.domain/dir/xxx` works fine. 192.168.1.1 is a IP of server's interface.

- apache listen on `0.0.0.0:80`
- no firewall

Looks like proxying to domain resolved as loopback interface doesn't work for some reason. I don't understand why I'd like to know how to make it work as such a setup would simplify my configuration for multiple servers.

Comment: "I got 5xx code" - 500? Or some other 5xx error? Check your error log for details.

Comment: 502 also ```[Wed Sep 06 10:36:56.137196 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 16113] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 127.0.0.1:52264] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server x-service.local:80
[Wed Sep 06 10:36:56.137218 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 16113] [client 127.0.0.1:52264] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /dir/xxx ```